# Is this a valid proof? (Cosets of vector subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I have been trying to think of an alternate way to construct this proof because I think this is a bit ugly, but I've decided to settle on this way. I'm just not sure if it's a valid way though.

**Background**

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$. For some fixed $\mathbf{v} \in V$, a coset of $W$ is defined to be the set

$$
\{\mathbf{v}\} + W = \{ \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w} \,\,|\,\, \mathbf{w} \in W \}.
$$
We usually denote this as $\mathbf{v} + W$, though.

**Problem**

I am trying to show that, for fixed $\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2} \in V$, if $\mathbf{v_1} + W = \mathbf{v_2} + W$ then $\mathbf{v_1} - \mathbf{v_2} \in W$.

**My Proof**

Suppose $W = \{\mathbf{w_1}, \mathbf{w_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{w_n}\}$. Then,

$$
\mathbf{v_1} + W = \mathbf{v_2} + W \implies 
\{ \mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_n} \} = 
\{ \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_n} \}.
$$

Let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \,\,|\,\, 1 \leq x_i \leq n, \, x_i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be an arbitrary ordering of the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Then suppose, without loss of generality, that,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_1} &= \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_{x_1}},\\
\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_2} &= \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_{x_2}},\\
&\ldots\\
\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_n} &= \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_{x_n}}.
\end{align*}
$$
More succinctly, $\mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{w_i} = \mathbf{v_2} + \mathbf{w_{x_i}}$
$\forall i = 1, 2, ... n$.

Rearranging, $\mathbf{v_1} - \mathbf{v_2} = \mathbf{w_{x_i}} - \mathbf{w_i} \in W$ because $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Therefore, $\mathbf{v_1} - \mathbf{v_2} \in W$.

Comment: The problem here is that you are assuming that $W$ is a finite set. A typical vector space is rarely a finite set.

Comment: The proof would be easier if you use the fact that $0\in W$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, you are absolutely right. I will edit the question to clarify, but my course only deals with finite vector spaces so it was assumed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm very surprised that you course only deals with finite vector spaces. Many courses deal with finite-dimensional vector spaces, but non-trivial finite vector spaces only exist when the scalar field is a finite field.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ugh, brain fart. Of course, I was thinking finite-dimensional vector spaces. For some reason in my mind, this was the same thing. Okay now I understand why this proof makes no sense haha.

Comment: $\mathbf v_2 \in \mathbf v_2 + \mathbf W$.  If $\mathbf v_1 + \mathbf W = \mathbf v_2 + \mathbf W$, then $\mathbf v_2 \in \mathbf v_1 + \mathbf W$. So, for some $\mathbf w \in \mathbf W,  \mathbf v_1 =  \mathbf v_2 + w$. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to suppose $W= \{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$. This will assume that $M$ is finite set. But vector spaces are usually infinite set. So you shouldn't write $W= \{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$.

Instead, you can just write: for some $w_1 \in W$, since $v_1+w_1 \in v_2+W$  so there exists $w_2 \in W$ so $v_1+w_1=v_2+w_2$ or $v_1-v_2=w_2-w_1 \in W$.